# How to upload and display image django 2?

Tags: python, django, image-uploading

I tried to hardcode path and nothing worked. What's wrong with my code? I'm getting 404 error and image isn't showing up.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'blog/media')
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/', blank = True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

forms.py
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:

        model = Post
        fields = ('author','title', 'text','image')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent'}),
        }
```

html

```
        <img src="{{post.image.url}}">
```

Comment: Couple of questions before writing an answer: 
Does it show up in `debug=True` without the `static()` part in urlpatterns? What is the actual `src` constructed in the template as in what you see in the browser when you check the html code?

Comment: static() part doesn't change anything, second answer is "<img src="/media/media/linux.png">" and there is a photo at this directory, still 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

from what I understand you are trying to make the django serve static files with this, static-files and media are separate, that line you have serves statics like css, js etc which resides in `STATIC_ROOT` while you need to serve `MEDIA_ROOT` so

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

adding this part should work, but I highly discourage using this in the actual deployment, media files should be handled by a web server like nginx and not an application server.

Comment: It's exercise site, but I'll read about web servers.Thanks a lot it works!